# How could i cancel any current await .then((value){....}

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am using `Firestore` as backend to my app

in my app users could signUp then login in using `Firabese auth`like any app . also they can switch their accounts to another if they have many accounts.

in my app i have many `.get().then((value){....}` like following ..

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
.limit(20)
.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server)).then((value){
   // here i am using some tasks to init some global variables like following
   // myGlobalVariable = value.get('name');       
});
```

Firstore is awesome and fast and it take maybe a second to after .get() function and run what inside .then((value){....}

but after many tests in months work. i noticed sometimes there is 5-8 sec to finish from .get() and this of course because some slow connection of the users side or any reason else . To be honest, this rarely happens . But this keeps worrying me because of the following

1- user login in using `account 1`

2- user have some `.get().then((value){myGlobalVariable = value.get('name');}` methods (Some delay happened for some reason)

3- before `.get().then((value){myGlobalVariable = value.get('name');}` is done, user switch his account to`account 2`

4- `.get().then((value){myGlobalVariable = value.get('name');}` successfully done after user successfully done log in `account 2`

here is some disaster happened . because `myGlobalVariable` has old value from first old account .

in the fact it is just simple example . i have lots of global variables and some tasks within `.then((value){....}` that per  `.then((value){....}` depends only in current account

How could i make sure and cancel the whole current pending `.then((value){....}  before user switch to another account .

or at least what is the best way to avoid this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1. Pass the current user's UID to the function that starts reading the user's data from Firestore.
2. Once then `then` callback fires add a check that the *current* UID is still the same as what you were called with.

Comment: this is what i am doing now . i thought there will be another better way to avoid this like cancel method to all current pending task instead of chick method to per function . thanks Frank